# Identity closure on references

Tags: reference, rust, closures, lifetime

I have a function that takes a closure. The closure takes a reference and returns any type `K`:

```
fn take_closure<T, K>(f: impl FnMut(&T)->K) {/*...*/}
```

If I call `take_closure` with an identity function, i.e.

```
struct S;
fn test() {
    take_closure(|s: &S| s)
}
```

the compiler complains:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
```

I think the problem is that `K` is one single type, but the closure must work for all lifetimes so that the closure's result must be something like `K + '(lifetime of closure parameter)`.

Specifying that `K` lives as long as `&T` does not really help:

```
fn take_closure<'a, T: 'a + Default, K: 'a>(mut f: impl FnMut(&'a T)->K) {
    let t = Default::default();
    f(&t); // error[E0597]: `t` does not live long enough
}
```

Thus, I tried higher-rank trait bounds:

```
fn take_closure<F, T: Default, K>(mut f: F)
    where for<'a> F: FnMut(&'a T)->K // <- (how) can I specify that K: 'a 
{
    let t = Default::default();
    f(&t);
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct S;
fn test() {
    take_closure(|s: &S| s) // error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
}
```

Is there a way to specify `take_closure` accordingly? I.e. can I somehow specify that `for<'a>`, my `FnMut(&'a T)` produces a `K` satisfying lifetime `'a`?

Comment: How exactly do you propose to convert `&S` (borrowed) into `K` (owned) by just returning `s` (borrowed), exactly? There's something very fishy going on there.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I think `K` is not necessarily owned. In particular, we chould have `K==&S` (at least that's what I think).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify when you declare your function that `K` must not outlive `&T`:

```rust
fn take_closure<'a, T: 'a, K: 'a>(f: impl FnMut(&'a T)->K) {}

struct S;
fn test() {
    take_closure(|s: &S| s)
}
```

Comment: I simplified my problem too much, sorry. Actually, I tried this, but this does not work out if I actually want to use `f` within `take_closure`. I think I - at least - have to specify arbitrary lifetime for `FnMut` (see my edited question). Thanks anyway for your answer.